# WFS won't load properly in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geoserver, wfs

I am trying to access a WFS from geoserver in QGIS, and when I load it, it comes in very strangely:

[image]

I can access it directly from the postgres database and it comes in fine. I'm wondering if there are settings to the geoserver layer I can adjust so that it comes in properly? WMS comes in ok, except when zoomed to full extent not all the features draw, in areas where there are a lot of polygons (it is a parcel layer with @ 170K records). When I zoom in on the WMS, the feature draw. But I'd really like to figure out what is going on with the WFS. I've also tried to load in feature for a limited extent with the same result.

Comment: Can you see if it's an issue with rendering? I've seen this a couple times on Windows PCs when "Render layers in parallel using many CPU cores" is activated, or "Feature Simplification" is enabled for that layer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Where can I find those settings? The feature simplification one sounds familiar but I just checked the layer properties and I don't see it.

Comment: I did find that feature simplification option checked under the data store, I unchecked that option but the data is still loading the same way.

Comment: A few questions come to mind: What does GeoServer report as the layer's SRS? What is QGIS using for the CRS? Finally, what's the WFS url that you are using?

Comment: QGIS and geoserver CRS both 3857. The url is http://52.24.37.126:8080/geoserver/Iada_workspace/ows? and I am trying to load in the parcels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know the main reason but the GML from the service has some odd coordinate values:

http://52.24.37.126:8080/geoserver/Iada_workspace/ows?service=wfs&version=1.0.0&request=getfeature&typename=Iada_workspace:parcels&maxfeatures=100

> gml:coordinates xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" ts=" " cs=","
>   decimal=".">-1.295840489020236E7,5410000.64865586,0
>   -Infinity,-1.295837966400454E7,5410000.48182336 0,-Infinity,-1.295837994378932E7 5409958.2865818,0,-Infinity
>   -1.295839798043889E7,5409958.40587354,0 -Infinity,-1.295840516987279E7,5409958.45341379 -1.295840489020236E7,5410000.64865586,0

It looks like your data have XYZ coordinates with all the Z values of "-Infinity". Perhaps that makes problems for QGIS. Because you do not seem to know real Z I would have a try by converting parcel polygons into XY geometries and publishing these 2D parcels as a new feature type.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that was it. I stripped the z and m values from the layer and now it loads just as it should.